# Call MeekroDB Within Function

Tags: php

A newbie question. How to call MeekroDB Class within function?

```
function get_forms($parent_id=0){
global DB;
$result = array();
$Forms=DB::query("SELECT id_form, name, title, description, url, icon FROM vas.forms WHERE parent_id=%i ORDER BY id_form", $parent_id);
print_r($Forms);

//return $result;}
```

There should be any results but it is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `global DB`. It causes a syntax error.

You're using static definition of Meekro so DB::query() is enough to call it.